# How to add multiple docs to a collection in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im working with React native and react-native-firebase

My objective is to add multiple docs(objects) to a collection at once.
Currently, I have this:

```
const array = [
  {
     name: 'a'
  },{
    name: 'b'
  }
]
array.forEach((doc) => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('col').add(doc);
}
```

This triggers an update on other devices for each update made to the collection. 
How can I batch these docs together for ONE update?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can create batch write like

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var batch = db.batch()
```

in you array add updates

```
array.forEach((doc) => {
  var docRef = db.collection("col").doc(); //automatically generate unique id
  batch.set(docRef, doc);
});
```

finally you have to commit that

```
batch.commit()
```

Comment: Were you able to get the generated unique id in the same call as the commit? I am thinking I would have to retrieve this by calling another get method..

Comment: How would you use a custom id for the document?

Comment: @rbansal Just set it. Document method accepting string

Answer (score 21):

You can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations. A batch of writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents.

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var batch = db.batch();

array.forEach((doc) => {

  batch.set(db.collection('col').doc(), doc);
}
// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you

Comment: Is this considered as a single write for cost or as the number of array elements?

Answer (score 7):

Version 9 of Web API is slightly different, [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) include this example:

```js
import { writeBatch, doc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Get a new write batch
const batch = writeBatch(db);

// Set the value of 'NYC'
const nycRef = doc(db, "cities", "NYC");
batch.set(nycRef, {name: "New York City"});

// Update the population of 'SF'
const sfRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
batch.update(sfRef, {"population": 1000000});

// Delete the city 'LA'
const laRef = doc(db, "cities", "LA");
batch.delete(laRef);

// Commit the batch
await batch.commit();
```

Comment: what if I want the firestore to generate the id?

Answer (score 5):

The batch from database also has a create function that adds a new document in a collection and throws an error if there is already a document. we just need the reference to the document. Please note that this function exists in admin sdk of firebase.

```
const batch = db.batch();
await users.map(async (item)=> {
    const collectionRef = await db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).doc();
    batch.create(collectionRef, item);
  });

const result = await batch.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

*A batched write can contain up to 500 operations. Each operation in the batch counts separately towards your Cloud Firestore usage.*

Note: For bulk data entry, use a [server client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries#server_client_libraries) library with parallelized individual writes. Batched writes perform better than serialized writes but not better than parallel writes. You should use a [server client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries#server_client_libraries) library for bulk data operations and not a mobile/web SDK.

Comment: Tell us how did you come up with this. Did you read the answer below?

Comment: @Mises because some people think that writing in batches might save their write quota, but it is not firebase charges you separately for each writes object in the batch.

Comment: @Mises it is not the answer but relevant to the answer, thank you.